# Integer Time Series compression

Tags: algorithm, stream, compression, delta

Is there a well known documented algorithm for (positive) integer streams / time series compression, that would:

- have variable bit length
- work on deltas

My input data is a stream of temperature measurements from a sensor (more specifically a TMP36 read out by an Arduino). It is physically impossible that big jumps occur between measurements (time constant of sensor). I therefore think my compression algorithm should work on deltas (set a base on stream start and then only difference to next value). Because gaps are limited, I want variable bit length, because differences lower than 4 fit on 2 bits, lower than 8 on 3 bits and so on... But there is a dilemma between telling in stream the bit size of the next delta and just working on, say, 3 bit deltas and telling size only when bigger for instance.

Any idea what algorithm solves than one?

Comment: Why reinvent the compression scheme? Couldn't you just pipe the output of your raw bit implementation into a standard algorithm like gzip?

Comment: Sounds like [Huffman coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding#Basic_technique) of the deltas is what you're looking for.

Comment: Huffman coding will give you the tightest possible per-symbol encoding, if you have reasonably accurate per-symbol probabilities (which are easy to get just from running it for a while).  If you want something simple and still decent, look at the [Elias codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elias_gamma_coding).

Comment: Ok for Huffman coding on variable-length integers. I'll use a modified version of 3bit words as my deltas are likely (over 0.5 probability) lower than 4. And run the stats on two days of recording to get a good sample. The reason why I don't use zlib or gzip is because I know very well my data and because I need to encode on chip with about 15kb of code space left.

Answer (score 1):

Use [variable-length integers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_quantity) to code the deltas between values, and feed that to [zlib](http://zlib.net/) to do the compression.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Integer compression methods with delta or delta of delta encoding like used in [TurboPFor Integer Compression](https://github.com/powturbo/TurboPFor). Gamma coding can be also used if the deltas have very small values.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there are different formats in existent. One thing I would do first is getting rid of the sign. A sign is usually a distraction when thinking about compression. I usually use the scheme where every positive is 2*v and every negative value is just 2*(-v)-1. So 0 = 0,  -1 = 1, 1 = 2, -2 = 3, 2 = 4... .

Since with that scheme you have nothing like 0b11111111 = -1 the leading bits are gone. Now you can think about how to compress those symbols / numbers. One thing you can do is create a representive sample and use it to train a static huffman code. This should be possible within your on chip constraints. Another more simple aproach is using huffman codes for bit lengths and write the bits to stream. So 0 = bitlength 0, -1 = bitlength 1, 2,3 = bitlength length 2, ... . By using huffman codes to describe this bitlength you become quite compact literals.

I usually use a mixture. I use the most frequent symbols / values as raw values and use not so frequent numbers by using bit lengths + bit pattern of the actual value. This way you stay compact and do not have to deal with excessive tables (there are only 64 symbols for 64 bits lengths possible).

Also there are other schemes like leading bit where for example of every byte the first bit (or the highest) marks the last byte of the value so as long as the bit is set there will be another byte for the integer. If it is zero its the last byte of the value.

I usually train a static huffman code for such purposes. Its easy and you can even do the encoding and decoding becoming source code / generate source code out from your code (simply create ifs/switch statements and write your tables as arrays in your code).

Answer (score 0):

The current state of the art for this problem is [pcodec](https://github.com/mwlon/quantile-compression). It compresses numerical sequences such as integers and typically achieves at least 30% higher compression ratio than other approaches. It automatically detects and applies the best delta encoding order as a built-in feature.

CLI example:

```bash
pcodec compress \
  --csv my.csv \
  --col-name my_col \
  out.pco
```

Rust API example:

```rust
let my_nums: Vec<i64> = ...
let bytes: Vec<u8> = pco::standalone::auto_compress(&my_nums);
println!("compressed down to {} bytes", bytes.len());
```

Since your data comes from a temperature sensor, your data should be very smooth, and you may even consider delta orders higher than 1 (e.g. delta order 2 is "delta-of-deltas").